# Determining Angular Material 2 icon ligature names

Tags: angular-material2

How can I determine the ligature names for the icons within the Material Design icon set?

Repository:

https://github.com/google/material-design-icons

Documentation:

https://design.google.com/icons/

The documentation lists the icons with a name below each - but the documentation doesn't provide instructions for how to reference each icon from within your application.

I guessed the following with mixed results:

`<md-icon>close</md-icon>` works - an `X` icon is shown

`<md-icon>help outline</md-icon>` fails - the word `help` is shown

Answer (score 1):

I was just having the same problem. I was fooling around until I found the following solution: if you write your icon name in snake_case, the desired icon appears.

E.g.

```
<md-icon>keyboard_arrow_left</md-icon>
```

This renders the small, left-pointing arrow.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It was not obvious - you have to click on the icon in which you are interested and a slider comes in from the bottom that shows the available sizes for the icon, allows you to display it in black or white, allows you to download it as a `SVG` or `PNGS` file... and clicking the `<> ICON FONT` (expand button) causes the slider to grow larger to show the I presume is Material 1 syntax to include the selected icon in an application...

this last tidbit includes the name and HEX code of the icon... which is what I wanted... yay!?

Instructions on the section of the page where the icons are listed would have been helpful...